# Add navbar link in Ionic tab child view

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a child view in a tabbed Ionic app like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="My View">
  <ion-content>
    My Page Content
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

how do I add a link in the navbar? I simply want an "Edit" link on the right side of the navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the following code between your `<ion-view>` and `<ion-content>`:

```
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear" ng-click="yourButtonFunction()">
      <i class="icon ion-edit"></i> Edit
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

here is the [official docs about it](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavButtons/)

Comment: Thanks @niklas.  I had `<ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>` surrounding the nav-buttons and it was not working properly.